# Is there any way I can identify when my Android app is built by F-Droid?

Tags: android, admob

I have a GPL android app, which has recently been included in F-Droid.

In the Google Play's I'm using AdMob to receive some income, but when the app is built by F-Droid servers, they use [this AdMob clone](https://github.com/mar-v-in/MobAdMob/) so the code builds without the need of adding a binary proprietary library. Because of that, ads are not shown.

However, I would like to add a small "banner" that allow users to visit my site when the ad is not shown: I won't have the direct income the adds give me, but at least  I'll allow users to go to my page and, if they want, give a donation.

My question is: is ther any way to know "IM_USING_THE_REAL_ADMOB" in the following code?

Another option would be to know who signed the APP.

Any help?

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.adLayout);

if(IM_USING_THE_REAL_ADMOB) { 
    // Google Play version of the app

    adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "ad-code");

    layout.addView(adView);

    AdRequest request = new AdRequest();

    adView.loadAd(request);
} else {

    // F-Droid versions of the App
    ImageView myImage;        

    layout.AddView(image)
}
```

---

I tried to look at the signature, as "CommonsWare suggested, by doing this

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
try {
    PackageInfo a = pm.getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
    byte[] raw = a.signatures[0].toByteArray();

    String sig = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5").digest(raw).toString();

    _sourceTextEditor.setText(sig);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {

        return false;
    }
```

but i got different result in two phones installing the same signed app. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the replacement AdMob's AdView will always return false to isReady and isRefreshing - maybe compare this behavior to the expected AdView behavior from the official AdMob and adjust your app accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, but I'd like to know before loading the ad, as with the real AdMob that can also happen sometimes.

Answer (score 2):

I would agree with powerj1984 that the right answer is for the faux AdMob library to let you know that it is the faux AdMob library.

If, for whatever reason, that is not possible, you can find out the details of the public key of the keystore that signed your app. Use [`PackageManager` and `getPackageInfo()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getPackageInfo%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) to retrieve the `PackageInfo` for your own package, specifying `GET_SIGNATURES` as the flag. The `signatures` field on `PackageInfo` contains an array of signatures, where there should only be one. That, in turn, is really the `byte[]` representation of a `X509Certificate`. [This sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/MiscSecurity/SigDump) shows how to display signature information for any installed app.

Comment: I've tried to obtain the signature, but I get a different one when opened in two different phones (installing the same apk), so I could not use it to differentiate between my own signed app (PlayStore) againt others (FDroid).

Maybe I'm using it wrong.

Comment: @XaviIvars: What is your means of comparison to indicate that they are different?

Comment: I've looked at a MD5 hash of the signature, and used it to compare, and it was different both for the debug package in the emulator vs the signed app in my phone (which makes sense, as they were different signatures) and was also different for the same signed app in another phone (which doesn't make sense at all)

Comment: @XaviIvars: Try decoding and dumping the contents of the signature, to make sure that you have the right signatures.

Answer (score 0):

If your app is GPL, people have both the source, and have the right to modify the source.  There is no way to force them to provide you with an income.

Comment: I know they have the right to modify the source. In fact, that's something I wanted when I first published my app as GPL. And I'm not trying to prevent anyone using that code in any way: what I wanted to achieve with that alt ad (an image) is to show some information regarding the site that supports the service (a non-profit ORG's site, btw).

Also, what I do want is that if someone wants "a different" app in any sense (like "the same app without ads or images") they have, at least, to modify the code to remove the apps, that's it.